# Performance between search in List<> and Query

Tags: c#, performance, dynamics-crm

I work with data migration from `Staging` to `Microsoft Dynamic CRM` using SDK I have problem about speed performance.

I have some question between performance about using `List<>` and `SQL Query` for Search Existing Data.

my question is

1. Between search existing data in `List<>` and `Query from DataBase`
   row by row which is faster ( **about 100,000 Object in List or
   100,000 Record in DataBase** ) If use this method connect database at once.
2. I think DataBase use `index` should faster than search in Object
   List right ? but if I use Query for search existing data (100,000
   record) it's must open and query 100,000 times

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using any profilers? There's tons of suggestions on how to view the performance out there on that ol' WWW :)

Comment: That depends. If your objects don't change, I would read them in on startup into a *List* serving as cache, that would be the fastest way in my eyes. If the objects change during runtime, I'd create a *covering index* in the DB on the table(s) based on the properties you need.

Comment: There's always hashset - by my understanding and testing, much faster than either for 100,000 members

Comment: No i never try before .I just compare between my method ( query existing data from database) and my friend method ( check existing data by search in list ) @Geoff James

Comment: I've been dealing with this a lot lately, and if you can partition your List/HashSet by count or first letter into a Dictionary<string,HashSet<>> you'll really fly! I'm cross-comparing a "list" of 2.7Billion members in batches of about 50,000, and creating about 2,500 lists per second using Dictionary<HashSet<T>>

Answer (score 1):

Example (obviously you'd want to optimize this - it's just an idea):

```
private Dictionary<string, HashSet<person>> peopleList = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<person>>();
    public void loadPeople()

    {
        List<person> people = new List<person>();
        people.Add(new person() { firstName = "Shirley", lastName = "Kotarski", age = 45 });
        people.Add(new person() { firstName = "Bob", lastName = "Smith", age = 24 });
        people.Add(new person() { firstName = "Bill", lastName = "Jones", age = 32 });
        people.Add(new person() { firstName = "Jim", lastName = "Hostettler", age = 19 });
        people.Add(new person() { firstName = "Ralph", lastName = "Billings", age = 27 });
        people.Add(new person() { firstName = "Eddir", lastName = "Johnson", age = 58 });
        for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++)
        {//Partitions based on first letter of first name
            string charI = ((char)i).ToString();
            string key = charI;
            peopleList.Add(key, new HashSet<person>(people.Where(p => p.firstName.Substring(0, 1) == charI).ToArray()));

        }
    }
    public void processListOfPeople()
    {
        for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++)
        {
            string charI = ((char)i).ToString();
            string key = charI;
            List<person> people = peopleList[key].ToList();
         }
    }
    public person lookupPerson(string firstName)
    {
        person p = new so_Win.person();
        string key = firstName.Substring(0, 1);
        return peopleList[key].Where(m => m.firstName == firstName).ToArray()[0];
    }
```